# AndroidStudio not showing .gradle files

Tags: android-studio

As said by the title, I cannot find any .gradle file and i dont understand why.
My project works and compiles fine, I dont have any problem inside the IDE but I would like to add SherlockActionBars, and to do that I have to modify settings.gradle and build.gradle, but I just can't find those two files anywere.
NB: The project was imported from eclipse

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can just create these files, if it is compiling and working fine in Android Studio 0.2.2 then likely they can just be manually created.

One thing, you said you imported from Eclipse - but did you do the manual step of exporting while in Eclipse?  Also - I suggest the eclipse be the version that comes with the Gootle ADT download.

Steps on exporting: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html